# Spring security Userdetails cannot be cast to my own user implementation

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I have a `User` class that implements the spring security `UserDetails`. However, during authentication of a login request, it gives a `ClassCastException` that `UserDetails` cannot be cast to my `User` class.

The full error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to
> class nl.teamrepositories.vliegmaatschappij.security.domain.User
> (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User is in unnamed
> module of loader 'app';
> nl.teamrepositories.vliegmaatschappij.security.domain.User is in
> unnamed module of loader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
> @6ef8cb6)

User:

```java
package nl.teamrepositories.vliegmaatschappij.security.domain;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean tokenExpired;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```java
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal(); // this is where the error occurs
    // more code
}
```

I don't see why my `User` class cannot be cast to the `UserDetails` class of Spring.

What should I change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your imports in `JwtAuthenticationFilter`. I guess you are using `import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` instead of your own class `import nl.teamrepositories.vliegmaatschappij.security.domain.User`:

```java
import nl.teamrepositories.vliegmaatschappij.security.domain.User;
(...)

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter {
    (...)

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal(); // this is where the error occurs
        // more code
    }
}
```

Either here or at some place else in your code you are using the wrong `User` class (Spring one instead of yours).